# Insert new block inside of checkout/cart

Tags: magento

My final goal of my plugin project is to let an image be uploaded to the database (done) have it do some functionality (done), and then let it be placed in some arbitrary spot on checkout/cart by the admin (oh the horror).

I’m first just trying to hardcode the .phtml into any block on this page (let’s use “checkout.cart.coupon” for sake of discussion).  My xml looks like this:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="embeds/projecttemplates" name="project.offers.embed" template="project/button.phtml" after="checkout.cart.coupon">
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

With this, my block just appears at the end of the page.  Changing after to before just shifts it all the way to the top.  Using a combination of before and after still keeps it at the top of the page.  Is there any way to get it to stay where I tell it to without having to resort to Prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a block named "new" to render inside the coupon block, you must do two things as the coupon block uses a template.

Step 1: Make the "new" block a child of the parent block via

```
<reference name="checkout.cart.coupon" />
```

or by using

```
parent="checkout.cart.coupon"
```

attribute in your block declaration.

Step 2: Customize the coupon template so that it renders your block with:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('project.offers.embed') ?>
```

If you want to get all metaphysically deep and **not** use a template, you *could* do the following, which would be sweet:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="coupon.and.offers" as="coupon">
            <!--
                This block will displace the existing coupon block by alias,
                but sill leave the coupon block instance in layout so it
                can be added as a child.
            -->
            <action method="insert">
                <block>checkout.cart.coupon</block>
            </action>
            <block type="embeds/projecttemplates" name="project.offers.embed" template="project/button.phtml" after="checkout.cart.coupon" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The first one definitely works, but has the issue of being deleted by Magento updates.  I may have to use it if I don't find any other solutions.

As for the second one, I couldn't get that to work.  All it did was create a second coupon block and then create my new block.  Playing around with it (and fixing the </coupon> to </block>) didn't help very much.

Comment: You need to do both steps I mention, and you should do them in *local.xml* layout file - let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Sorry, I misinterpreted it! Will most likely be able to try it out on Tuesday.  Will let you know then.

Comment: I couldn't really get the XML version working, so I'm going with the template version.  To make it more customizable (for my purposes), I took out the reference and <checkout_cart_index> so any other template can use "$this->getBlockHtml" instead of getChildHtml, which didn't seem to work everywhere even when it was global.

Thanks for your help!